# How does SAS calculate standard errors of coefficients in logistic regression?

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I am doing a logistic regression of a binary dependent variable on a four-value multinomial (categorical) independent variable. Somebody suggested to me that it was better to put the independent variable in as multinomial rather than as three binary variables, even though SAS seems to treat the multinomial as if it is three binaries. THeir reason was that, if given a multinomial, SAS would report std errors and confidence intervals for the three binary variables 'relative to the omitted variable', whereas if given three binaries it would report them 'relative to all cases where the variable was zero'.

When I do the regression both ways and compare, I see that nearly all results are the same, including fit statistics, Odds Ratio estimates and confidence intervals for odds ratios. But the coefficient estimates and conf intervals for those differ between the two.

From my reading of the underlying theory,as presented in Hosmer and Lemeshow's 'Applied Logistic Regression', the estimates and conf intervals reported by SAS for the coefficients are consistent with the theory for the regression using three binary independent variables, but not for the one using a 4-value multinomial.

I think the difference may have something to do with SAS's choice of 'design variables', as for the binary regression the values are 0 and 1, whereas for the multinomial they are -1 and 1. But I don't really understand what SAS is doing there.

Does anybody know how SAS's approach differs between the two regressions, and/or can explain the differences in the outputs?

Here is a link to the SAS output:
[SAS output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzhHdoyabCjnN0hkRDRyWVZKbGs)

And here is the SAS code:

```
proc logistic data=tab descending; 
  class  binB binC binD  / descending;
  model y =  binD binC binB ; 
run; 
proc logistic data=tab descending; 
  class multi / descending;
  model y =  multi; 
run;
```

Comment: This question is probably better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, the difference is the result of the chosen design coding.  The different codings will produce different covariance matrices, which will produce differences in the standard errors.

Comment: I think this post explains the answer to your question.  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/proc_logistic_coding.htm